# Generic parameter could not be inferred - Array extension

Tags: ios, swift

I have generic method to create object that extend protocol `FromResponse`.

```
extension FromResponse {
    static func object<T>(_ response: [String: Any]?) -> T? where T: FromResponse, T: NSObject {
        guard let response = response else { return nil }
        let obj: T = T()
        return obj
    }
}
```

So whenever I want to call it from anywhere in a code there is no issue. Let's say:

```
let myObject: MyObject? = MyObject.object(response)
```

Work's perfectly. But sometimes I'm getting array of objects from my response so I would like to have generic parser as well:

```
static func objects<T>(_ response: [[String: Any]]?) -> [T]? where T: FromResponse, T: NSObject {
    guard let response = response else { return nil }
    var returnArray: [T] = [T]()
    for singleResponse in response {
        if let object: T = T.object(singleResponse) {
            returnArray.append(object)
        }
    }
    return returnArray
}
```

So I expect from this method to return array of `MyObject`, but In fact I'm getting compiler error when I'm calling this:

```
let myObjects: [MyObject]? = MyObject.objects(response)
```

It says:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Well, I know what does it mean but I did specify type, so this error should not happen. Also when I do this:

```
var typ: [MyObject] = [MyObject]()
for singleResponse in (response as? [[String: Any]])! {
    let pack: MyObject? = MyObject.object(singleResponse)
    typ.append(pack!)
 }
```

It works!

Why? How to have parser that returns array of generics objects?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of `MyObject` (and the `response` you pass as the argument)? I cannot reproduce your problem. Though you can completely avoid this need for type inference by having the methods return `Self?` and `[Self]?` respectively (you can constrain the extension with `where Self : NSObject` if necessary). You may even want to consider making `object(_:)` an initialiser.

Comment: Turns out that was a Xcode strange behavior, after quit and clear DD it's compile... Thanks for comment that you cannot reproduce a problem. That makes me do it ‍♀️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know for sure why Swift says “Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred”, but my guess is it has to do with array covariance.

What's covariance? Consider this:

```
class Base { }
class Sub: Base { }
func f(_ array: [Base]) { }
```

Can you pass an `[Sub]` to `f`? In Swift, you can. Because `Sub` is a subtype of `Base`, `[Sub]` is a subtype of `[Base]`. (This is called “covariance”.) So you can pass a `[Sub]` anywhere that a `[Base]` is allowed:

```
f([Sub]())
// No errors.
```

And you can return a `[Sub]` where a `[Base]` is expected:

```
func g() -> [Base] { return [Sub]() }
// No errors.
```

And you can assign a `[Sub]` to a `[Base]` variable:

```
let bases: [Base] = [Sub]()
// No errors.
```

So back to your code:

```
static func objects<T>(_ response: [[String: Any]]?) -> [T]? ...

let myObjects: [MyObject]? = MyObject.objects(response)
```

Certainly `MyObject.objects(_:)` must return a type that can be treated as `[MyObject]?`. But any subtype of `[MyObject]?` is also acceptable. The type is not tightly constrained. I guess this is why Swift doesn't like it.

The fix is to tell Swift explicitly what type you want, using a pattern you'll see in many places in the Swift standard library:

```
static func objects<T>(ofType type: T.Type, from response: [[String: Any]]?) -> [T]? ...
// Note that you might not actually have to use the `type` parameter
// in the method definition.

let myObjects = MyObject.objects(ofType: MyObject.self, from: response)
```

It's not clear why this method is on the `MyObject` class at all. Perhaps you should make it a method on `[[String: Any]]`:

```
extension Collection where Element == [String: Any] { 
    func objects<T>(ofType type: T.Type) -> [T]? ...
} 

let myObjects = response.objects(ofType: MyObject.self)
```